# How to use different controllers, depending on the user role, for the same route?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-routing

I'm trying to implement multiple controllers which listens to one route `/account`.

There are two controllers and only one should be executed on that URL where the choice lies within user's role.

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Role;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/account")
 */
abstract class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    protected $userRoles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userRoles = $this->getUser()->getRoles();
    }

    /**
     * Get all user roles
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->userRoles;
    }

    /**
     * Get user account type
     *
     * @return Role
     */
    public function getAccountType(): Role
    {
        $accountType = new Role();
        foreach ($this->userRoles as $role) {
            if(Role::ROLE_STUDENT == $role->getName()) {
                $accountType = $role;
            } else if(Role::ROLE_SCHOOL_REPRESENTATIVE == $role->getName()) {
                $accountType = $role;
            } else if(Role::ROLE_EMPLOYER == $role->getName()) {
                $accountType = $role;
            } else if(Role::ROLE_ADMIN == $role->getName()) {
                $accountType = $role;
            }
        }

        return $accountType;
    }
}
```

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

class CompanyDashboardController extends DashboardController
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="dashboard_company_home", methods={"GET"})
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('dashboard/company/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

class AdminDashboardController extends DashboardController
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="dashboard_admin_home", methods={"GET"})
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('dashboard/admin/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

That's what I've got so far.

Comment: Why not include the return statements in the appropriate `getAccountType()` method? For example, `if(Role::ROLE_ADMIN == $role->getName()) { return $this->render('dashboard/admin/index.html.twig');...`

Comment: Because there are many other files and those two dashboards act differently.They've got nothing in common.As I mentioned, I must render one controller according to some condition, and in our case, that's user's role.

Comment: A question: does the path to the route `/account` appear in more than one place? If only one place another option is to use Twig's `{% if is_granted(...) %} {{render(controller...` as in this [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#embedding-controllers)

Comment: That path occurs only once, the url is being changed, after logging in, to `/account`.Then the main controller (DashboardController) must decide which one to execute.I've never worked with embedded controllers but I will check it.More advice will be appreciated!

Comment: an alternative is the `forward` method every default controller has, with which you could implement a "multiplexer" (which this essentially is) very basic docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/forwarding.html you can't have two routes with the same path, they will override one another (the latter wins), so you need a "central" route that forwards to the appropriate methods/controllers. or you chose different paths, which would probably be much simpler.

Comment: Please show how `...the url is being changed, after logging in...`

Comment: Pretty simple.After post request in order to try to sign in, on success, we redirect to the respective path: `window.location.href = '/account';`And then logic begins.But, I believe this is harder as Jakumi said.I'll reckon on refactoring the whole thing.The easier way would be just to have three different urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't do this with "route" declarations, since the route listener is executed with higher priority than the security listener**. Both happen during the `KernelEvents::REQUEST` event, but routing comes before firewall.

When the route to controller mapping is being resolved, you do not have yet user information (which is why you can't simply attach another a listener and inject the user information on the `Request` object, so it's available to use in the route declaration for [expression matching](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#matching-expressions), for example).

Basically, one route, one controller. If you want to have diverging logic for these users, you'll have to apply it **after** you get into the controller.